# Adding a GPU Op in Tensorflow

Tags: python, c++, cuda, tensorflow

I am trying to add a new op to TensorFlow loosely following [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op) document. The difference being that I am trying to implement a GPU based op. The op I'm trying to add is the cuda op from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/adding_an_op) (cuda_op.py, cuda_op_kernel.cc, cuda_op_kernel.cu.cc). I am trying to compile these outside of tensorflow and the use `tf.load_op_library` to pull them in. I have made some changes so here are my files:

cuda_op_kernel.cc

```
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/op.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/shape_inference.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h"

using namespace tensorflow;  // NOLINT(build/namespaces)

REGISTER_OP("AddOne")
    .Input("input: int32")
    .Output("output: int32")
    .SetShapeFn([](::tensorflow::shape_inference::InferenceContext* c) {
      c->set_output(0, c->input(0));
      return Status::OK();
    });

void AddOneKernelLauncher(const int* in, const int N, int* out);

class AddOneOp : public OpKernel {
 public:
  explicit AddOneOp(OpKernelConstruction* context) : OpKernel(context) {}

  void Compute(OpKernelContext* context) override {
    // Grab the input tensor
    const Tensor& input_tensor = context->input(0);
    auto input = input_tensor.flat<int32>();

    // Create an output tensor
    Tensor* output_tensor = NULL;
    OP_REQUIRES_OK(context, context->allocate_output(0, input_tensor.shape(),
                                                     &output_tensor));
    auto output = output_tensor->template flat<int32>();

    // Set all but the first element of the output tensor to 0.
    const int N = input.size();
    // Call the cuda kernel launcher
    AddOneKernelLauncher(input.data(), N, output.data());

  }
};

REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER(Name("AddOne").Device(DEVICE_GPU), AddOneOp);
```

cuda_op_kernel.cu

```
#define EIGEN_USE_GPU
#include <cuda.h>
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void AddOneKernel(const int* in, const int N, int* out) {
  for (int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x; i < N;
       i += blockDim.x * gridDim.x) {
    out[i] = in[i] + 1;
  }
}

void AddOneKernelLauncher(const int* in, const int N, int* out) {
  AddOneKernel<<<32, 256>>>(in, N, out);

  cudaError_t cudaerr = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  if (cudaerr != cudaSuccess)
    printf("kernel launch failed with error \"%s\".\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudaerr));
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

#found from running python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.sysconfig.get_include())'
include_directories(/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/include)

find_package(CUDA)

#set flags based on tutorial
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "--std=c++11 -fPIC -O2 -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0")

#pass flags to c++ compiler
SET(CUDA_PROPAGATE_HOST_FLAGS ON)

#create library
cuda_add_library(
    cuda_op SHARED
    src/cuda_op_kernel.cu
    src/cuda_op_kernel.cc
    OPTIONS -gencode=arch=compute_20,code=sm_20)

#copy test file to build folder
configure_file(src/test.py test.py COPYONLY)
```

test.py

```
import tensorflow as tf
mod = tf.load_op_library('./libcuda_op.so')
with tf.Session() as sess:
    start = [5,4,3,2,1]
    print(start)
    print(mod.add_one(start).eval())
```

I am able to compile and run `test.py` successfully, but the output is always `[0 0 0 0 0]`. If I replace `AddOneKernel<<<32, 256>>>(in, N, out);` with `for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) out[i] = in[i] + 1;` and `DEVICE_GPU` with `DEVICE_CPU`, the op outputs the right values `[6 5 4 3 2]` (with exact same `CMakeList.txt`).

Any idea how to get the correct values to be returned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't fully remember where I found the cmake stuff for CUDA, but the options were messing the compilation up somehow. Replacing `cuda_add_library` in the `CMakeLists.txt` to be the following fixed the problem.

```
#no options needed
cuda_add_library(
    cuda_op SHARED
    src/cuda_op_kernel.cu
    src/cuda_op_kernel.cc)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the current official GPU ops building instructions on [Tensorflow adding GPU op support](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op#gpu_support)

```
nvcc -std=c++11 -c -o cuda_op_kernel.cu.o cuda_op_kernel.cu.cc \
  ${TF_CFLAGS[@]} -D GOOGLE_CUDA=1 -x cu -Xcompiler -fPIC

g++ -std=c++11 -shared -o cuda_op_kernel.so cuda_op_kernel.cc \
  cuda_op_kernel.cu.o ${TF_CFLAGS[@]} -fPIC -lcudart ${TF_LFLAGS[@]}
```

As it says, Note that if your CUDA libraries are not installed in `/usr/local/lib64`, you'll need to specify the path explicitly in the second (g++) command above. For example, add `-L /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/` if your CUDA is installed in `/usr/local/cuda-8.0`.

Also, Note in some linux settings, additional options to nvcc compiling step are needed. Add `-D_MWAITXINTRIN_H_INCLUDED` to the nvcc command line to avoid errors from `mwaitxintrin.h`.

Answer (score 0):

ubuntu@cubuntu:~/Desktop/src/src/build$ cmake ..

-- Configuring done

-- Generating done

-- Build files have been written to: /home/ubuntu/Desktop/src/src/build

ubuntu@cubuntu:~/Desktop/src/src/build$ make

[ 33%] Building NVCC (Device) object CMakeFiles/cuda_op.d/cuda_op_generated_cuda_op_kernel.cu.o

nvcc warning : The 'compute_20', 'sm_20', and 'sm_21' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release (Use -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets to suppress warning).

nvcc warning : The 'compute_20', 'sm_20', and 'sm_21' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release (Use -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets to suppress warning).

Scanning dependencies of target cuda_op

[ 66%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cuda_op.dir/cuda_op_kernel.cc.o
/home/ubuntu/Desktop/src/src/cuda_op_kernel.cc:1:17: error: ‘tensorflow’ is not a namespace-name 
using namespace tensorflow;  // NOLINT(build/namespaces)

Comment: I was trying to follow your example but when perform make, it complain about the tensorflow namespace?! What could be the problem?

Comment: A bit late to reply, but you should create a new question for this.